# Reopen "How to find out knowledge level of coworker" [done]

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

I'd like to request to reopen [How can I improve my communication with my less skilled coworker?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/103640/how-to-find-out-knowledge-level-of-coworker).

It was closed for being too broad, but this question seems clearly answerable to me (and the upvoted answers support that). The question is asking how to effectively and professionally communicate technical knowledge when you don't know the knowledge level of your coworker. This is a relatively common problem faced in the workplace and should fit right in our wheelhouse.

**Update:** That was reopened quickly, thanks!

Comment: I think we have a tendency to label anything without a definitive answer or with multiple valid answers as "too broad" or "unclear" which I think is a mistake.  Granted, that's a discussion for another place however.  Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has been reopened.